# Права доступа к папке в Android

Tags: java, android

В ходе работы приложения создаю папку и помещаю туда фото с камеры.

```
File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyFolder");
```

Проблема в том, что папка получается приватная и доступа из вне к ней и файлам в ней нет.

Это не помогает:

```
mediaStorageDir.setReadable(true);
mediaStorageDir.setWritable(true);
```

Как можно решить проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Согласно примеру на сайте [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#PublicFiles) вам не хватило вызова ещё одной команды: `mkdirs()` для того, чтобы создать сам каталог и путь до него, а не файл.